# Download/Upload of Page Remarkup in Phabricator Wiki (Phriction)

Tags: phabricator

The company I work for uses the "Phriction" wiki in [Phabricator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phabricator) for a considerable amount of documentation. I'd like to be able do the following, programmatically, in order of importance:

1. Download (e.g., with `curl` or `wget`) the [ReStructuredTExt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) (RST) to a local file where I can edit it, diff it, etc. Ideally I should be able to download either the latest version or any specific version.
2. Locally render (e.g., in a local graphical web browser) the markup as Phabricator would render it. If relative links can link correctly back to the original wiki, that's a bonus.
3. Upload new versions of the wiki page.

If you have don't know how to do exactly any of this, but have information or tool suggestions that would help me get started on writing software to do the above, please mention them. (If you're worried about too many answers that don't actually answer any of the questions above, try adding or editing a single community answer for this sort of information.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following in your situation:

1. Downloading the single phriction pages using the API ([Conduit](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/)) methods in the phriction section.

   - Therefore you need a Conduit Api Token. You can create  in your profile settings of your phabricators intstance.
   - Then take a look at the [phriction.info](https://secure.phabricator.com/api/phriction.info) mehtod: This methods needs the page slug as parameter. In this example I use the `/changelog/` page.
   - You can choose between arcanist, cURl or PHP to use the RestApi. Additionally you can use any other way to preform RestApi commands in the cURL syntax.
     [image: Example]
   - If you need some more examples how to run the conduit method you can toggle between some variations at the bottom of the output page.
2. Transform the page content as you like.
3. Upload the page again with the conduit methods ([phriction.edit](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/phriction.edit/)).

   - The way you downloaded the content you can edit the documents, too. But here you need some more parameter:
     [image: phriction.edit example]

I personally, try first all conduit methods via the web interface first and then transform it to an a script.

Comment: Would you care to expand your answer to provide a short example shell script? If so, I'll mark it as accepted. Otherwise no fear; when I have time I'll generate an example and post it as an answer.

Comment: I need to take a look at some similar stuff I've done at work. I will paste some more details later today. Do you need a shell/script  - or does some powershell snippets help you as well?